# How to calculate the probability of a set of a certain data "A" to have higher values than "B" using exceedance analysis?

Tags: bayesian

Here is the data I'm using this set of data frame:

```
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
$ trat: Factor w/ 2 levels "F","U": 1 1 1 2 2 2
$ n   : num  1 2 3 1 2 3
$ yield: num  268329 279375 307701 293721 93195 85956
```

I've tried to calculate the exceedance probability in which the "trat" "F" would possess higher values of yield than "trat" "U".

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(rstanarm)
```

First, I've tried to establish a Bayesian model prior to the exceedance analysis:

```
model <- stan_glm(yield ~ trat, data = df, family = gaussian(), chains = 4, iter = 2000)
```

Then I've extracted the posterior samples using the following script:
`posterior_samples <- as.matrix(model)`

But, then, when I've tried to calculate the exceedance probability of mean of "trat" "F" being higher than "trat" "U", in which I suppose it would be something like:

```
prob <- mean(posterior_samples[, "tratF"] > posterior_samples[, "tratU"])
```

I would not complete because the posterior_samples would only return three columns `(Intercept), tratU, sigma`. It cannot complete because there is a lack of column "tratF". How can I correct the script?